# How to set conditional rendering of a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a function with a language toggle. Now i want to have a conditional rendering of the buttons with the value of the function, example, 'nl' as language is clicked, nl button disappears. I already made start with the const languageIsEnglish

```
export default function App({ path }) {
  const Page = pageRenderers[path]
  const [language, setLanguage] = React.useState('nl')
  return (
    <I18nProvider value={i18n} {...{ language }}>
      <Page onLanguageChange={setLanguage} />
    </I18nProvider>
  )
}
export function NavigationDesktop({ links, onLanguageChange }) {
  const languageIsEnglish = onLanguageChange
return (
    <button onClick={() => onLanguageChange('en')} className={styles.languageToggle}>En</button>
     <button onClick={() => onLanguageChange('nl')} className={styles.languageToggle}>Nl</button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to render one button but change what to pass to the callback and the label according to the currently active language:

```
return (
    <button 
      onClick={() => onLanguageChange(language == 'nl' ? 'en' : 'nl')} 
      className={styles.languageToggle}
    >
      {language == 'nl' ? 'En' : 'Nl'}
    </button>
)
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work with more than 2 languages? :D

Comment: Then it should not be toggle (means switch b/w 2 values), dude @VivekDoshi :D

Comment: Glad, you get it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with ternary operator :

```
return (language === 'nl' ? 
    <button onClick={() => onLanguageChange('en')} className={styles.languageToggle}>En</button> :
     <button onClick={() => onLanguageChange('nl')} className={styles.languageToggle}>Nl</button>)
```

---

**Working code snippet :**

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {

  const [language,setLanguage] = useState('nl');

  function changeLanguage(lang) {
    setLanguage(lang);
  }

  return (
      language === 'nl' ? 
      <button onClick={() => changeLanguage('en')}>En</button> :
      <button onClick={() => changeLanguage('nl')}>Nl</button>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work with more than 2 languages?

Comment: Then it should not be toggle (means switch b/w 2 values), dude @trixn

Answer (score 0):

For more than two languages, the ternary operator won't work. We can use switch case like this

In render function

```
export default function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {getButton('nl')}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In getButton function we can use switch like this

```
const getButton = (language) => {
  switch(language) {
    case 'en':
      return <button onClick={() => onLanguageChange(language)}>{language.toUpperCase()}</button>
    case 'nl':
      return <button onClick={() => onLanguageChange(language)}>{language.toUpperCase()}</button>
    default:
      // default language
      break;
  }
}
```

This way we can achieve the conditionally rendor the buttons.